# Can I use 'javascript_include_tag' with `content_for(:head)` in show.html.erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Why do I get this error?
Can I use `javascript_include_tag` with `content_for(:head)`  in show.html.erb?
I'd like to put the line to load js within `<head>...</head>`

If I put `<%= content_for(:head) do %>`, the line of loading "refresh_chat.js" won't appear.
If I remove `<%= content_for(:head) do %>`, the line of loading "refresh_chat.js" appears, but not in `<head>`

**views/posts/show.html.erb**

```
1. <%= content_for(:head) do %>
2.   <%= javascript_include_tag "refresh_chat.js" %>
3. <% end %>
```

Comment: Ref http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work. Make sure you `yield` in the `<head>` section:

```
<head>
  ...
  <%= yield :head %>
</head>
```

and then

```
<% content_for(:head) do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "refresh_chat.js" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

You might not want to output the content_for block (`<% content_for ...`) in your partial. Also `content_for(:head)` is not a magical feature or something. If you want to put the contents of it into your head you have to do something like this in your layout:

```
<head>
  ...
  <%= yield(:head) if content_for?(:head) %>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just use `<% content_for(:head) do %>` instead of `<%= content_for(:head) do %>`, so that the content isn't rendered in your view but in your `<head>`.